# Is there any way for autosize in bokeh tables?

Tags: python, user-interface, bokeh

I am trying to find out how to enable subj. I will create many table and choose size every time manually is a little annoying. As I understand there is not any "official" way to do it, but maybe there is an easy way to do int with another libraries? Coz now I don't have better way than transfer full table (every item|cell) to strings, and set width of columns based on max length of item in every column and resulted width as sum of them.
Any ideas, how to make it better and easier? With a library or smth like that.